# Unable to predeploy PersistenceUnit [PU] in invalid state [DeployFailed]

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, vaadin

I am using EclipseLink as my JPA provider. My application was working correctly but lately it is giving me an error when I deploy the application and it is not working anymore. I am new to JPA and although I have read the logs I can't understand what is going on. It is something related with EclipseLink-93 and EclipseLink-41 exception. Can somebody help me? Thank you in advance.

```
Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [CONTACT] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(science.softdev.SongPromoter.model.Album --> [DatabaseTable(ALBUM)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(science.softdev.SongPromoter.model.Album --  [DatabaseTable(ALBUM)])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1656)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:130)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:188)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at science.softdev.SongPromoter.Persistance.<clinit>(Persistance.java:16)
... 67 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28017] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Unable to predeploy PersistenceUnit [PU] in invalid state [DeployFailed].
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [PU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
```

This is the code of my Album and Contact classes:

```
package science.softdev.SongPromoter.model;


import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
public class Album {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idAlbum;
private String albumUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
private String name;
private String author;
private boolean active = true;
private String simplifiedDate;
private String zipUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
private String description = "";

public int getIdAlbum() {
    return idAlbum;
}

public void setIdAlbum(int idAlbum) {
    this.idAlbum = idAlbum;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getZipUUID() {
    return zipUUID;
}

public void setZipUUID(String zipUUID) {
    this.zipUUID = zipUUID;
}

public String getSimplifiedDate() {
    return simplifiedDate;
}

public void setSimplifiedDate(String simplifiedDate) {
    this.simplifiedDate = simplifiedDate;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}

public void setAlbumUUID(String albumUUID) {
    this.albumUUID = albumUUID;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

private String cover;
private String coverUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

public String getCoverUUID() {
    return coverUUID;
}

public void setCoverUUID(String coverUUID) {
    this.coverUUID = coverUUID;
}

private String zipLocation;
private Date releaseDate;

public String getAlbumUUID() {
    return albumUUID;
}

public String getZipLocation() {
    return zipLocation;
}

public void setZipLocation(String zipLocation) {
    this.zipLocation = zipLocation;
}

public Date getReleaseDate() {
    return releaseDate;
}

public void setReleaseDate(Date releaseDate) {
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
}

public String getCover() {
    return cover;
}

public void setCover(String cover) {
    this.cover = cover;
}

public void setMixes(List<Mix> mixes) {
    this.mixes = mixes;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy="album",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Mix> mixes = new ArrayList<Mix>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="author",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<Review>();

public List<Review> getReviews() {
    return reviews;
}

public void setReviews(List<Review> reviews) {
    this.reviews = reviews;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<Mix> getMixes() {
    return mixes;
}

public void setMixes(ArrayList<Mix> mixes) {
    this.mixes = mixes;
}
}
```

And this is Contact class:

```
package science.softdev.SongPromoter.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;


@Entity
public class Contact {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idContact;
private String name;
private String email;
private String contactUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
private boolean active;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<Review>();

public List<Review> getReviews() {
    return reviews;
}

public void setReviews(List<Review> reviews) {
    this.reviews = reviews;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}

public String getContactUUID() {
    return contactUUID;
}

public void setContactUUID(String contactUUID) {
    this.contactUUID = contactUUID;
}

public int getIdContact() {
    return idContact;
}

public void setIdContact(int id) {
    this.idContact = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem by changing my persistance provider from EclipeLink to Hibernate (Running in Payara server 4.1). I could not find any resources on the internet related to this issue that could help me out. It **might** be an unreported bug with EclipseLink 2.6.3 as just switching the JPA provider solved the issue.